# Ways to structure a program with 2 states

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I'm working on some sort of a Level Editor but I'm not quite sure how I want to handle the two different states: The Editor state and the Player state.

In this first state game elements can be moved around and tiles can be drawn.

In the second state the game elements get their physicsbodies and the player can be moved around using the keyboard.

Now what I'd like to know is what the best way would be to structure these states. Most of my objects behave differently depending on the state in which the game is.

One way to deal with this would be to give everything two versions of the update and draw methods. An updateEditor and updatePlayer for instance.

Another way would be to have a base class for let's say a game element, and derive an EditorGameElement en PlayerGameElement from it, but I feel like that would be a bit of an overkill, besides that I wouldn't know how that would work since I'd have two objects that inherits frome a single object.

What other ways are there to deal with a structure like this?

Comment: Not really an answer but if you based your design on MVC. You just have one model with either one view but 2 differents controller, or 2 view and each one its controller. Having one view with 2 different controllers may not be so easy so it could definitively be better to start from two differents views and their associated controller.

Comment: @Walfrat never seen MVC for non-serverside things yet, I'm a bit afraid that it would require a massive code overhaul though.

Comment: You have a user interaction, so you have definitively a view, you have data, so you have a model, you need comminucation between them, so you have a controller to ensure this. Of course others design can work but MVC definitively have his place there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than think of this as a state of the system I'm inclined to think of it as a few capabilities you either do or don't have access to as a player.

Some basic abilities:

- Copy objects ([prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern))
- Move objects (could be as simple as select object, move player & object, release object)
- Save objects (as fancy as serialization or as simple as making `toString()` something a constructor can read)

You could show an object as selected with an outline.

I once designed and built a universal board game that had the editor and the game as the same UI.  You created objects (pieces) by simply dragging them from a pallet of objects into the game board.  Once there, they could be moved around, deleted, or saved with the rest of the game.

That isn't the same as a 3D level editor but the principles are the same.  Every manipulation from the controller should update the model.  Every time the model is changed, update the view.

MVC is really just a separation of responsibilities.  If you want to learn how to comunicate between these areas so you can cleanly swap out views, models, and controllers then look up the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep this difference in the `Scene` object (a container for for all game elements).

For the "game" mode it will only allow to move the player, but not other elements. And special `Scene` subclass can be used for level editor.

It can work in a following way:

```
// create the scene
scene = new Scene();
// add game elements (probably these will be read from the level file)
scene->add(new Box(x, y));
scene->add(new Wall(x1, y1, x2, y2));
scene->add(new Player);

// move player to the different place, probably as a reaction to keyboard input
scene->movePlayer(x2, y2);
```

And the level editor could work like this:

```
scene = new SceneEditor();
// add game elements (probably these will be read from the level file)
scene->add(new Box(x, y));
scene->add(new Wall(x1, y1, x2, y2));
...
// select the object (as a reaction to mouse click)
anObject = scene->selectObject(x, y);
// move object to another place
scene->moveObject(anObject, x2, y2);
// save the modified level
scene->saveToFile(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say keep it simple:

Make 1 program that's the editor and another program where you play the game. This way you can make editobjects for your editor and playobjects for your game without needing to mix and match functionality that essentially does not belong together.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. The editor has to be part of the whole as it is not just a dev-tool, but actually an important part of the game. Besides that keeping it in different programs sounds like a terrible idea since there would be a lot of redundant code.

Comment: @Oli414 having it in two seperate programs is a great idea and the way that most gamedevelopers do it. Take starcraft: the game and the editor are 2 very different programs, with both their own strengths. By separating it you can have each tailor made to the end user: the level maker and the game player.

Comment: As I said, it is not a solution to the problem in my case. The editor is not just a developers-tool, but is actually part of the game (Look at Mario Maker for example).